# is MySQL Connector/Python greenlet safe?

Tags: python, mysql, greenlets

I'd like to know whether the **MySQL Connector/Python driver** is greenlet safe.  Their site [1] doesn't mention anything about greenlets.  Just that it's thread safe.

Some searching leads me to gevent-MySQL (dead) which leads me to amysql (deprecated) which leads me to ultramysql (not PEP 249 compliant, no doc, etc.).  Also I'm reading here [2] that pymysql might do it.

Before I switch to pymysql, does anyone have experience with the MySQL Connector/Python driver and greenlets?  Any of the authors here?

[1] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html

[2] http://engineering.pinterest.com/post/65713073803/how-we-use-gevent-to-go-fast

Comment: Did you ever get an answer?